# Atom gcc-linter for kernel development

Tags: linux-kernel, atom-editor, linter

I'm working on a kernel module. I chose Atom as my editor of choice.

It's nice to have a working linter. I installed the linter-gcc engine, now it complains about missing `linux/module.h`. This header is provided by the kernel build system, so plain gcc will fail to find it.

Is there any way to work it around?